# How to get remote users to authenticate?

Tags: domain, domain-controller, remote-access, remote

We have some remote users who are rarely on the company LAN.  They may be remote for six months or more during a year.  Every so often we encounter the problem of errors like: "There are currently no logon servers available to service this request" and sometimes "The trust relationship between this workstation and the primary domain failed".  All of the laptops are Windows 7 Pro.

At first I thought it was an issue with the cached credentials expiring, but from what I have read, the credentials don't expire.  The DC is Server2012R2, and it is set to the default setting for Interactive logon: Number of previous logons to cache, which should allow for 10 credentials to be cached.  There is no way that 10 different people have logged on to these machines, maybe two or three at most, and that's if someone from the IT team has logged on.

Everything I find suggests this shouldn't be happening.  My question is do others encounter this type of problem, and what do you do to resolve it?  Thanks.

Comment: Try to disable machine account password change. https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2009/02/15/machine-account-password-process-2/

Comment: Thanks yagmoth555, I ran across this article too.  I will discuss this with the team and if we decide to implement it I will post the results.

Comment: If it work let me know, will transfer the info as an answer with the blog contents.